# I can't select an html element that was created dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selector

I have an html file

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

Then I dynamically change the content with js

```
$.get("foo.html", function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

foo.html is an external html file that looks like this

```
<span id="results">
</span>
```

This works to change the content of my page. I have checked in Chrome's dev tools, the page now looks like this

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <span id="results">
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Great. Now I want to display some results with jQuery

```
$("#results").text("some text");
```

This last part does not work. I can only assume it is because #results was created dynamically. I know of this problem with event handlers and using `on` instead of `click` but that is not the case here. I am simply trying to select the element.

Of course my actual code is much more complicated and I have left some stuff out. If you think there is something else that may be causing the problem please tell me and I will check.

Comment: You have invalid closing tags - is that just here, or in your actual code?

Comment: close `</span>` properly.

Comment: When do you call $("#results").text("some text"); ?
i.e. how do you make sure that the page content is loaded before making the call?

Comment: Where did you put this `$("#results").text("some text");` statement? It should be **after** your AJAX call completes and **after** you insert the new content into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @fbuendia, that was the problem. I was 95% sure it wasn't but I checked my code again and it was.

Answer (score 1):

$.get is an asynchronous function, meaning it doesn't wait for completion before moving on.  The way how jQuery gets around this is by using callback functions.  Here, we have defined a callback function.  We need to put the text modification inside the $.get callback.

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get("foo.html", function(data){ //$.get callback function(data)
    $("#content").html(data);
    $("#results").text("some text");
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if O/p wants to set it sometime else?

Comment: Then, @ILike, the OP should have stated that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an invalid closing tag `</span` should be `</span>`
2. Make sure `<span id="results">` exists on the page when you're acting on it.  Because you are loading the content dynamically, there is a race condition, so act on it after it has loaded:

   ```
   $.get(…).done(function(){
      $('#results').text('foo')
   });
   ```

---

Beyond this, more information will need to be shown, perhaps a fiddle or code snippet.